# How can I use a String, which is defined inside of a loop, in another class?

Tags: java, string, class, for-loop, jframe

So I already succesfully coded a password generator, but I now want to create a JFrame that prints out the created password. 
This is my code:
class passwort

```
    public class passwort
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Passwortgenerator fritz = new Passwortgenerator();       
        fritz.passwortausgeben();
    }
}
```

class Passwortgenerator

```
public class Passwortgenerator
{
   public int x;

    public Passwortgenerator() {
        this(1);
    }
    public Passwortgenerator(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }   
    public void passwortausgeben(){

            int d=Zufallsgenerator.zufallszahl();
            int k=0;


                String[] alpha = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1"};

                for(int i=0; i<alpha.length; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<alpha.length; j++){
                        for(int l=0; l<alpha.length; l++){
                            for(int m=0; m<alpha.length; m++){


                                if( k<d ){
                                    k++;


                                }else{
                                    System.out.print(k + " " + alpha[i] + alpha[j] + alpha[l] + alpha[m]);

                                    String y=k + " " + alpha[i] + alpha[j] + alpha[l] + alpha[m];


                                    System.out.print(y);
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }        
            }
        }
```

class Zufallsgenerator:

```
import java.util.Random;

public final class Zufallsgenerator
{
    public void main(String[] args){
        zufallszahl();
    }
    public static int zufallszahl(){
        Random Hanz = new Random();
        int d = Hanz.nextInt(100000);
        return d;


    }

}
```

class Fenster:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public final class Fenster
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        JFrame meinFrame = new JFrame("3");        
        meinFrame.setSize(200,200);
        meinFrame.add(new JLabel(y));
        meinFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine, but I can't find a way to call the JFrame class and how to get it to use the String created by the second class. I already found out that you can't use String from within a loop, but I couldn't come up with any alternatives.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: When does the Fenster will get called ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I also don't know how to call this class. Do you have a suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: When this should be called ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I just started recently so I'm rather helpless.

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions. It's harder to read code that doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant parts of your design are this:

> ```
> public void passwortausgeben(){
>     // ...
>                                 System.out.print(y);
>                                 System.exit(0);
>  }
> ```

Your method not only generates the password, it also handles responsibility for displaying it to the user and also for controlling the life of your program (namely exiting immediately).

You really want to separate those concerns.  Change your method so that it only generates the password.  It doesn't need to be responsible for anything else.

```
public String passwortausgeben(){
    // ...
                                return y;
}
```

Then you can handle the other concerns separately.  For console use:

```
public class passwort
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Passwortgenerator fritz = new Passwortgenerator();       
        final String password = fritz.passwortausgeben();
        System.out.print(password);
        // Note: no System.exit() is actually needed here, since the method
        // will end, and all threads have terminated, so the program
        // will exit naturally.
    }
}
```

Then you can have an alternative that displays it in a Swing GUI.  For example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public final class Fenster
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Passwortgenerator fritz = new Passwortgenerator();       
        final String password = fritz.passwortausgeben();

        JFrame meinFrame = new JFrame("3");        
        meinFrame.setSize(200,200);
        meinFrame.add(new JLabel(password));
        meinFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Note that since your `Fenster` class has a "`main()`" method, you run it directly as your program.  Your `passwort` class will be unused.  If you are running your program on the command-line, and you are in the correct directory, then `java Fenster`.  If you are using an IDE, then you need to configure the run of your IDE to tell the Java runtime which class to use as the "main" class.

---

---

---

Complete example of one way to change `passwortausgeben()`.  As your compiler told you, the method does need to return a value.  This means it needs to return a value *in all cases*.  Since your successful generation is in a conditional statement, it may or may not happen.  (`d` could be too large, in which case you'll never produce a password)

```
public String passwortausgeben(){
    int d=Zufallsgenerator.zufallszahl();
    int k=0;

    String[] alpha = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1"};

    for(int i=0; i<alpha.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<alpha.length; j++){
            for(int l=0; l<alpha.length; l++){
                for(int m=0; m<alpha.length; m++){
                    if( k<d ){
                        k++;
                    }else{
                        String y=k + " " + alpha[i] + alpha[j] + alpha[l] + alpha[m];
                        return y;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("the loops all ended before k>=d, no password generated");
    }
```

An alternative way to design the method (this requires Java 8, which has been available for several years now):

```
public Optional<String> passwortausgeben(){
    int d=Zufallsgenerator.zufallszahl();
    int k=0;

    String[] alpha = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1"};

    for(int i=0; i<alpha.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<alpha.length; j++){
            for(int l=0; l<alpha.length; l++){
                for(int m=0; m<alpha.length; m++){
                    if( k<d ){
                        k++;
                    }else{
                        String y=k + " " + alpha[i] + alpha[j] + alpha[l] + alpha[m];
                        return Optional.of(y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Optional.empty();
    }
```

Or to avoid returning in the middle of the method.  This one is a little messier due to the deeply nested loops and the desire to stop doing useless work once the answer is known.  Each of your four loops needs to end, but a `break` will only end the loop that contains the `break` statement.  Java does have labels that can be used with the `break`, but these are almost never used nor remembered.

```
public Optional<String> passwortausgeben(){
    int d=Zufallsgenerator.zufallszahl();
    int k=0;

    String[] alpha = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1"};
    String result = null;

    for(int i=0; i<alpha.length && result==null; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<alpha.length && result==null; j++){
            for(int l=0; l<alpha.length && result==null; l++){
                for(int m=0; m<alpha.length && result==null; m++){
                    if( k<d ){
                        k++;
                    }else{
                        result = k + " " + alpha[i] + alpha[j] + alpha[l] + alpha[m];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Optional.ofNullable(result);
    }
```

Unrelated to your actual question, the loops can be eliminated and replaced with some division.

```
public String passwortausgeben(){
    int d=Zufallsgenerator.zufallszahl();
    final int k = d;

    String[] alpha = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1"};

    int i = d / (alpha.length*alpha.length*alpha.length);
    d -= (i*alpha.length*alpha.length*alpha.length);

    int j = d / (alpha.length*alpha.length);
    d -= (j*alpha.length*alpha.length);

    int l = d / alpha.length;

    // the remainder
    int m = d % alpha.length;

    if (i < alpha.length)
        { return k + " " + alpha[i] + alpha[j] + alpha[l] + alpha[m]; }
    else
        { throw new IllegalStateException("Number is too large. No password generated"); }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanaiton. Does this mean that I could delete the passwort class?

Comment: I also can't compile the Fenster class: It tells me that there are incompatible types int his line:        `final String password = fritz.passwortausgeben();`

Comment: Did you change the return type of `passwortausgeben()` from `void` to `String`?

Comment: I tried this, but then it needed a return statement and I also could place this anywhere, because it wouldn't let me compile it. If I write `return y;` at the end of the code, it can't find the variable.

Comment: That is correct. You need to change your method to return the string. And when you declare that it returns something, then you need to return it! I noted in my answer that you'll replace the "print" and "exit" with "return". Review any introduction to Java regarding the scope of variables (your variable `y` is out of scope by the end of your your method).

Comment: `if( k<d ){
                                    k++;
                                    
                                }else{
                                    
                                    String y=k + " " + alpha[i] + alpha[j] + alpha[l] + alpha[m];
                                    return y;
                                }` this is how i got the if loop, but this also doesnt let me compile because there is no return in the passwortausgebn method. Where do I have to place the return?

Comment: Sorry, if this is a bit too straight forward, but would u mind sending me the complete working code? I would be really grateful.